# Difference between starting coroutine with launch or with coroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

It seems I can start a coroutine using a number of mechanisms. Two of them are `coroutineScope` and `launch` but reading the Kotlin coroutine docs I am unclear what the difference is and when I would use one over the other

```
fun main() {
    println("Main block  ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    runBlocking {
        coroutineScope {
            println("Coroutine scope  ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
        launch {
            println("Launch  ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
}
```

I ran the above and can see that both start a new coroutine. What is the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `CoroutineScope` is an organisational thing - it lets you group coroutines together to enforce [*structured concurrency*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency). Basically, it allows you to control the lifetime of everything within the scope (including coroutines launched within other coroutines) and handles things like propagating results and errors, and cancelling everything within a scope. [More info here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/)

All the coroutine builder functions (including `launch`) run *inside* a `CoroutineScope` (or *on* it as a receiver, if you want to look at it that way):

```
fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext, 
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT, 
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job
```

So the `launch` call in your example is running *inside the current `CoroutineScope`*, which has been provided by the [`runBlocking` builder](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html):

```
expect fun <T> runBlocking(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): T
```

See how the lambda you're passing is actually a `CoroutineScope.() -> T`? It runs with a `CoroutineScope` as the receiver - that's what you're calling `launch` on. You can't call it from just anywhere!

So when you create a `CoroutineScope` in your example, you're nesting one *inside* this `CoroutineScope` that `runBlocking` is providing. `runBlocking` won't allow the rest of the code that follows it to continue (i.e. it *blocks* execution) until everything in its `CoroutineScope` has completed. Creating your own `CoroutineScope` inside there lets you define a subset of coroutines that you can control - you can `cancel` them, but if there are still other coroutines running in the `runBlocking` scope, it will keep blocking until they're done as well.

---

Like Louis says in the other answer, you're not actually creating any coroutines inside the scope you've created. The code is just running in the coroutine that `runBlocking` started to run the block of code you passed. Check this out:

```
fun main() {
    println("Main")
    runBlocking {
        coroutineScope {
            delay(1000)
            println("I'm in a coroutine scope")
        }
        launch {
            delay(500)
            println("First new coroutine")
        }
        launch {
            delay(50)
            println("Second new coroutine")
        }
    }
}
```

```
Main
I'm in a coroutine scope
Second new coroutine
First new coroutine
```

Code within a single coroutine executes sequentially - so what happens is

- You start in main
- You enter the `runBlocking` block's coroutine
- You create a `CoroutineScope` which only affects stuff you `launch` (etc) on it
- You delay, then print a line
- You hit the first `launch` and create a new coroutine. This starts off by delaying 500 ms, but it's running on its own now - different coroutines run *concurrently*
- You move onto the next line, and `launch` the second coroutine. That runs on its own too, and immediately delays 50ms. There are 3 coroutines running now
- You've finished executing the code in the block - this coroutine is done. *However*, there are two running coroutines that were also started on this `CoroutineScope`, so `runBlocking` waits for those to finish.
- The second coroutine with the shortest delay prints first, then finishes
- The first coroutine finishes last, because even though it was started earlier, they all run independently
- Now everything inside the `runBlocking` `CoroutineScope` is done, it can finish and allow execution to contine in `main()`

If you `launch`ed a coroutine inside that scope you created, it would all work the same way - it's just you'd have fine-grained control over the stuff in there in particular, and you could specifically work with the coroutines inside that nested scope without affecting things in the outer scope. All that matters is once that inner scope has completed, it can inform the outer scope that it's all done, that kind of thing

Comment: Not all coroutine builders run in a CoroutineScope.  runBlocking() neither requires a scope to be called, nor is it an extension function on CoroutineScope.

Comment: I think I now understand why there's confusion about this point.  This statement "runBlocking is also a coroutine builder ..." is made at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency.  On the other hand, the statement "Every **coroutine builder** (like [launch], [async], etc) is an extension on [CoroutineScope]..." is made in CoroutineScope.kt.  I know for a fact that runBlocking() is not a CoroutineScope extension function.

Answer (score 7):

`coroutineScope` doesn't start a new coroutine.

`launch` starts a new coroutine that can run concurrently with other coroutines.  `coroutineScope` does not.